# Creating generic helper functions

Tags: typescript

I have a "main" setter function which looks like this: `type Setter<S> = (s: S) => S`.

And I want to create a bunch of helper functions which operate on a state of a certain shape.

```
type Setter<S> = (s: S) => S

interface State {
  foo: number
}

declare const set: Setter<State>

function test<S extends {foo: number}>(setter: Setter<S>) {
  setter((s) => ({ ...s, foo: 123 }))
}

test(set)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhzAgJwDwwHxQLxQBQGcAuWASm0xgChKBLAO0SQDMBDAY2hmBcSgG9KUKEwD2I4nQCuAWwBGySgF9qAEwhsANiyTQ2IuvmBR88YnATI03ROmpNJdNsBr6oiQ2igQAHojor8flFxKCk5ZEV0AnhGMxjLDDIBIRMLJFwCMixMXD4oADpC-AAaYTFiAEYAJgBmKEUSEiVqd2Bo4CagA)

Unfortunately, this gives me an error: `Argument of type '(s: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'S'. 'S' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '(s: any) => any'.`

How should I type my `test` function to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems like I figured it out. I missed that it's a function that takes a function.

```
type Setter<S> = (s: S) => S

interface State {
  foo: number
}

declare const set: (s: Setter<State>) => void

function test<S extends {foo: number}>(setter: (s: Setter<S>) => void) {
  setter((s) => ({ ...s, foo: 123 }))
}

test(set)
```